Pass dataframe to tools from streamlit
I have a master_agent which is returning an agentexecutor, and using two tools, eda (llamaindex_query_engine) and another one, I want to pass the dataframe the user is uploading to the streamlit app using fileuploader, pass to the eda agent. Can anyone help?
